# How can I solve this linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

If given $T_1(x,y) = (2x + y, 4x+ 15y)$ How would I solve $T_1(x,y) = (-4,-1)$ for x and y?.

I tried forming a matrix and finding the RREF to get the solution, but the numbers I got did not make sense, and I am not sure how to solve it.

Comment: row reduction should work.  Show your steps in order for us to see what you're doing wrong.

Comment: " tried forming a matrix and finding the RREF to get the solution" That should have worked. "but the numbers I got did not make sense, and I am not sure how to solve it." Then you made an error.  Show us what you did and we'll see if we can find the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$2x+y = -4\\ 
4x+15y=-1$$

Solving using elimination gives $(x,y)=(-59/26,7/13)$

Answer (score 0):

"I tried forming a matrix and finding the RREF to get the solution, but the numbers I got did not make sense, and I am not sure how to solve it."

It should have worked.

$(2,1,-4)$ and $(4,15, -1)$ should give us:

$(4,2,-8)$ and $(4, 15, -1)$ should give us:

$(0, 13, 7)$ and $(4, 15, -1)$ should give us:

$(0, 1, \frac 7{13})$ and $(\frac 4{15}, 1, -\frac 1{15})$ should give us

$(0, 1, \frac 7{13})$ and $(\frac 4{15}, 0, -\frac 1{15}-\frac 7{13}$ should give us:

$(0, 1, \frac 7{13})$ and $(1, 0 , (-\frac 1{15}-\frac 7{13})\frac {15}4)$ which means

$y = \frac 7{13}$ and $x =  (-\frac 1{15}-\frac 7{13})\frac {15}4=-\frac 14 -\frac {7*15}{4*13}= -\frac {13+7*15}{4*13} = -\frac {105+13}{52}=\frac {118}{52}=-\frac {59}{26}$.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a linear transformation, you would want to turn it into a matrix then interpret it from there.

Like so.

$\displaystyle \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1\\ 4 & 15 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}  x \\ y \end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix}  -4 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}$

Then Cramer's rule can take over from there. But you can still go easy with this one. The function is well defined anyway so:

$2x+y=-4$

$4x+15y=-1$

$4x+2y=-8$

$13y=7$

$y=\dfrac{7}{13}$

$x=\dfrac{-4-\dfrac{7}{13}}{2}$

$=\dfrac{-59}{26}$

I think that should be it. But just because you mentioned linear algebra you can check out what I was saying https://youtu.be/jBsC34PxzoM there